# How do i summon an armor stand at a specific block (for example at red wool)

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im trying to get armor stands to spawn at all 6 sides of a specific block, in this case im using red wool.i have managed to do this by executing at named armor stands and detecting red wool block with ~~~, but im wondering is it possible to just spawn 6 armor stands at all sides on any red wool WITHOUT having an armor stand hovering above the block and detecting a red wool

I am on Xbox, so therefore in bedrock edition just to clarify, even though tag tells you that

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Nope, the answer is simply no. Your detection system where you run an armor stand along seems to be the best way. The only other solution would be if you knew for sure the blocks it could be, you could just hard code in checking all the coordinates and finding one with wool 14. Also I'd recommend giving the armor stand you use to perform the checks infinite Resistance 256 and Invisibility if you haven't already. Also make sure to use the hide particles argument to hide the effect particles.